# I calculated the following limit in Matlab and I am getting a piecewise as a result. What does that mean?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I tried to calculate this limit:

```
syms x c

Relative_forward_error = limit (1/tanh(c*x),x,0)
```

And I have the following result. I am not good at maths, so can anyone help me with this answer please. The symbol c is a constant.

```
piecewise(c == 0 | dx == 0, 0, dx ~= 0 & ~in(c, 'real'), -limit((c*dx*(tanh(c*x)^2 - 1))/tanh(c*x), x, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try plotting `tanh(x)` or `tanh(c*x)` in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh(x)).  Also try plotting `1/tanh(x)`.  According to the plot, what happens to `tanh(x)` as `x` goes to zero from the left and from the right?